# XULRunner Application Security Implementation

Tags: security, certificate, xulrunner

I'd like to incorporate security features in my standalone XULRunner app. Specifically, I'd like to use security certificates to validate the app executable as downloaded by a user. From what I've seen, its called code signing. But I'm very green in this area. Any pointers on how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use certificates for what exactly? Validate downloads? Authenticate users? Encrypt messages? Certificates are a tool, not a goal. Your question should state the goal that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more specific. From what I've seen, its code signing, but I'm very green in this area. Any pointers will be appreciated very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate functionality built into XULRunner isn't meant to validate signatures of Windows executables - you would need to use Windows functions for that (e.g. via [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes)). Not going to be simple however, [here](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/ac968ff4fe41/toolkit/components/maintenanceservice/certificatecheck.cpp#l52) you can see how that check works in C++ code.

However, if you are merely downloading an update to your application then maybe using an HTTPS connection would be sufficient - the origin of the executable is verified then (won't help you if that server is hacked however).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Palant. I'll try this out and report my findings here.

Comment: This has been very helpful in helping me understand the process. After several attempts and not getting this right, I realized that code signing functionality is included in Installshield, the utility I'm using to package the application. Along with this article at http://www.installationdeveloper.com/286/using-code-signing-certificates-in-installshield-part-1/, I was able to pull it off.